# VBA AutoShapeType Ignored When Macro Runs

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code:

```
Dim targetChart As Chart
Dim labelRange As Range

Set targetChart = Worksheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
Set labelRange = Worksheets("Graph").Range("H3", "H" & lastrow)

With targetChart.SeriesCollection(4)
        .ApplyDataLabels
        With .DataLabels
            .Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, labelRange.Address(External:=True), 0
            .ShowCategoryName = False
            .ShowRange = True
            .ShowSeriesName = False
            .ShowValue = False
        End With
    End With
```

I want to format my data labels as rounded rectangles, but when I run the macro the `.Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle` seems to not execute. When I step through the macro it doesn't throw an error so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Everything else within the with statement works as intended.

The reason I have `.ShowValue = False` is because I am setting the data label values from a range.

Comment: did you try doing it manually and recording a macro to see if this the exact correct syntax for that line of code?

Comment: I tried recording it and the syntax is Selection.Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle, so I assume what I have is proper without the selection. For testing I went ahead and left the select in and still no dice.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you may need to use `With targetChart.FullSeriesCollection(4)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad using FullSeriesCollection yields the same result as just .SeriesCollection.

Recording the action of making the shapes rounded rectangles and then running the macro also does not change the shapes.

Comment: Can you change the shape to rounded rectangle in the Excel app? I selected the labels but couldn't find where the GUI provides a choice of shapes.

Comment: @xidgel if you right-click on the data label one of the options is "Change Data Label Shapes"

Comment: I don't see that option in Office 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
targetChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    With targetChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
    .ShowRange = True
    .ShowValue = False
    .Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, labelRange.Address(External:=True), 0
    .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.5
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Format.Fill.Solid
End With
```

Comment: That worked! I guess it was creating the shape but because it wasn't being filled it never showed the shape.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel's Help it says that both `DataLabels.Format` (the entire `DataLabels` collection) and `DataLabel.Format` (a single `DataLabel`) are **read-only**. Maybe what you're trying can't be done.